# iOS View Controller is only accepting touches in a certain portion of the window

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a relatively simple dialog/popup style UIViewController that isn't behaving correctly. I have many others just like it (though each with a unique button layout) that work just fine. For some reason that I cannot figure out, this controller is only accepting touches within (approximately) the green shaded area.

Note that none of these colors are the actual colors, just placeholders. Same goes for the text.

Tapping in the "Search..." text field does nothing. Tapping on the "Cancel" button does nothing. No UI reaction whatsoever.

The tableview will scroll just fine (there are over 100 rows) if it's touched inside (approximately) the green region. Touching the tableview below the green results in no response. Same thing for the "Cats" button. It reacts when touched in approximately the top half, but nothing in the bottom half.

[image: This is the layout in Interface Builder]
[image: This is the view hierarchy]

I've banged my head against the wall for the requisite "several hours" and am getting nowhere.

Comment: What happens if you perform `viewController.view.clipsToBounds = YES` in advance of presentation (or tick the relevant box in the interface designer)?

Comment: That doesn't appear to do anything actually. I noticed that after placing the green box on the screen that I can only scroll the tableview by touching that tiny sliver at the top that's outside the box. This makes sense because the green box is "on top" of the tableview. I still can't scroll the tableview by touching below the green box though.

Comment: As a diagnostic, try writing a custom subclass of `UIView` and making that the root view of your controller. Override `- hitTest:withEvent:` and find out which view it's finding under different situations and/or whether it's being called at all.

Comment: @PhilRingsmuth , have you tried my suggest? Was it helpful?

Comment: @Avt, I did. See my response below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution. I have a method that launches a dialog controller given the dialog to launch and the parent (up until this point, always a full-screen view controller). The parent gets darkened and the dialog gets launched on the center of the screen.

This one wasn't working because I was launching it from an existing dialog; I was telling the dialog launcher that the new dialog's parent was the current dialog, not the whole screen. This means that the new dialog (which is bigger than the first one) launches at the correct size, but only accepts input inside the area of the "parent" dialog, which is the smaller one underneath it.

Fix: Launch the new dialog using the current dialog's parent (which is full screen) and it works fine. The green zone on my image is the approximate size of the dialog that was being used as the parent, which is why input was only being accepted in that area.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that part of your view controller's view is overlapped with some "harmful" view/views. Maybe this view is created programmatically and is not visible in IB. You should start with checking your views hierarchy. Put breakpoint in your view controller's code. Somewhere, where you are sure all views (normal and harmful) are already created and type in debug area

> po [self.view recursiveDescription]

you should receive something like
[image]

Now try to find harmful views. Temporarily delete some "normal" views could be a good idea.

Comment: I tried doing this and everything listed after issuing that command is accounted for. Their locations and sizes all match what I have in Interface Builder. Nothing is being altered programmatically either, it's loaded straight from the XIB file.